# Moxy: marshall without JAXB annotations like @XmlRootElement

Tags: moxy

Is it possible to marshall all Java POJOs to XML without using JAXB annotations without configuring every POJO class independently?

PS: the context is a Rest Resource with Jersey 2.

Answer (score 1):

[**JAXB (JSR-222)**](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementations including [MOXy](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) do not require any annotations.  In the absence of an `@XmlRootElement` annotation you need to wrap your object in an instance of `JAXBElement`.

```java
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class);

Foo foo = new Foo();
JAXBElement<Foo> je = new JAXBElement(new QName("root-element"), Foo.class, foo);

Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
marshaller.marshal(je, System.out);
```

**For More Information**

You can refer to the following article from my blog for a full example:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-no-annotations-required.html

Comment: Can MOXy be configured to wrap the data automatically in an JAXBElement? My rest resource returns the data and produces both JSON and XML (i.e wrapping the data on that level will create some problems with the JSON marshalling)?